# How to get page title in php?

Tags: php

I have this function to get title of a website:

```
function getTitle($Url){
$str = file_get_contents($Url);
if(strlen($str)>0){
    preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
    return $title[1];
}
}
```

However, this function make my page took too much time to response. Someone tell me to get title by request header of the website only, which won't read the whole file, but I don't know how. Can anyone please tell me which code and function i should use to do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: instead of `file_get_contents` use `curl` and get the content from URL and extract the title.

Comment: [Don't parse XHTML with regexes.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/344643)

Comment: Thank you, but can you show me the code to do this? I'm new to php.

Comment: If you are gonna use this method then it'd be best to only parse the first 10 to 20 lines of the file. Typically the title is within the first 5 lines. If not, its pure crap coding work.

Comment: It sounds great, how do I parse the first 10 lines of the file? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Using regex is not a good idea for HTML, use the DOM Parser instead

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('****'); //put url or filename  
$title = $html->find('title');
echo $title->plaintext;
```

or

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('*****');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('title') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

---

**Good read**

1. [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: It said: "Call to undefined function file_get_html()"
or "Class 'simple_html_dom' not found".

Should I simply copy those code in my php file and replace those ****? Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: @user1904449 download and include [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/)

Comment: Hi i know its late but this thread helped me http://www.idiotminds.com/get-any-website-page-title-from-url-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Instead to get Title of your page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($("title").text());
});​
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/WQNT8/1/

Comment: Thank you, dextor. But I want to get title of any website by inputting its url, not my page.

Answer (score 0):

try this will work surely

```
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$oHtml = str_get_html($url);
$Title = array_shift($oHtml->find('title'))->innertext;
$Description = array_shift($oHtml->find("meta[name='description']"))->content;
$keywords = array_shift($oHtml->find("meta[name='keywords']"))->content;
echo $title;
echo $Description;
echo $keywords;
```