# get the title of a page

Tags: php, html-parsing

i am getting the title of a page using the following

```
$urlContents = file_get_contents("$url");
preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i", $urlContents, $matches);
```

the problem i am having is one of the sites the title is on 3 lines

```
<head id="head"><title>
    title goes here
</title><meta name="description" content="meta description" />
```

this is for a basic onpage seo tool i am writing, is there a better way i can get the title of a page?

Thank you

Comment: Already answered

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027877/how-to-get-page-title-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just using plain js

```
var title = document.title
```

Or jquery

```
var title = $("head title")[0];
```

Comment: thanks for the reply its for an external website i have managed to find my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348912/get-title-of-website-via-link thank you

Answer (score 0):

i found my answer here

[Get title of website via link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348912/get-title-of-website-via-link)

```
$urlContents = file_get_contents("http://example.com/");

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($urlContents);

$title = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');

print($title->item(0)->nodeValue . "\n"); // "Example Web Page"
```

thank you

Answer (score -1):

I think there are character limits for the title. So title should not be in three lines. I have checked in Yoast plugin. It also saying the same. Then what is the purpose of getting three line seo title.