# How can I fetch the TITLE of my html page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to fetch the contents under MY TITLE to appear as title within an image on the same page. For example this is a link from my blog and the title of the page appears within the image.

Just a code to fetch my title and use it within an image without having to copy paste manually every time. The structure of my URL is (title.php)

Comment: Show the exact example or code snippet you tried.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you meant the page's title at the browser's tab, right? (question was a bit unclear)

If so, this value can be accessed in Javascript using

```
document.title
```

This is the cleanest way to get it, and the most effective one. There is a weird play if you want to use purely PHP to get it, however, I would stick to using this method if I were you.

For reference, here is the previous SO topic on getting page title in PHP

[How to get page title in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027877/how-to-get-page-title-in-php)

---

If you wanted to use that value in PHP, you could use Javascript inside PHP by simply writing

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> document.title </script>';
```

Comment: I'm not a pro when it comes to coding. How do I use document.title within a html page?

Comment: I understand that you want a quick and easy answer, however me providing it would only damage you on the longer term. I would highly recommend checking out a course on Javascript ES6 Essentials. This is related to the chapter DOM Manipulation, however I'm sure you'll require the whole course and not to skip anything through it. https://www.linkedin.com/learning/javascript-essential-training-3 is a course I would recommend.

Comment: Thanks a lot,,really appreciate this. Will definitely spend time to learn.